# "x-real-ip" & "x-forwarded-for" headers always null on ec2+tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, http-headers

I have a EC2 linux instance with a tomcat webapp (uses spring mvc) running on port 8081. There is no load balancer in place. I've setup the instance security group on the aws console to open up port 80. And on the ec2 inststance, I'm routing requests from port 80 to 8081 by doing

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8081
```

I need to access client's ip address (to determine their country). And so I'm looking for the x-forwarded-for and x-real-ip headers in the HttpServletRequest object.

The following always returns null when running on ec2, but returns valid values when running the same webapp on my local machine (and accessing via public ip using ngrok).

```
request.getHeader("x-forwarded-for") or request.getHeader("x-real-ip")
```

Is there any additional setup to be done on the AWS console or the EC2 instance to get the headers in the webapp? Or is the iptables routing messing up with the headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of your local testing, it's actually the `ngrok.com` service that's adding the `X-Real-Ip` and `X-Forwarded-Proto` headers, see [this comment](https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok/issues/92#issuecomment-47379544) from the creator for instance.

In your EC2 deployment, these headers might be added by a load balancer or reverse proxy, such an ELB, if you had one in place, but you state there is none.

In this case, you would need to look at the request's source IP address to determine its origin.

For development, you could do something like

```
request.getHeader("x-forwarded-for") or request.getRemoteAddr()
```

but this would leave you vulnerable to clients spoofing the `X-Forwarded-For` header. You should only trust these headers if the true remote address of the request is a reverse proxy or load balancer that you trust, such as one you control or a partner if you're using a CDN or third party DDoS protection.

Comment: This was it. I had not realized that x-real-ip wouldn't always be there. Falling back in the order x-forwarded-for > x-real-ip > getRemoteAddr() is working out perfectly for me. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Glad I was able to help.